# Не могу реализовать поиск по вводимому слову в ActionBar Android

Tags: android, поиск, search

Пишу муз.плеер и нужно реализовать поиск по `ListView` (у меня инфа выводимая во `View` содержится в `ArrayList < HashMap < String, Object > >`).
В одной строке `ListView` я вывожу три строки (Title Song, Album, Artist) , искать нужно по "Song Title", "Album" и "Artist" одновременно.

У меня есть рабочий код, который ищет по какому-нибудь одному параметру, а мне нужно, чтобы поиск выполнялся по трем одновременно.
Например, строка в списке: "название трека, имя исполнителя, название альбома" - нужно найти этот трек либо по названию трека, либо по названию альбома или по имени исполнителя. Рабочий код прилагаю.

```
 String searchString = searchBox.getText().toString();
            int textLength = searchString.length();
            listSongsForlistViewMainActivity.clear();

            for (int i = 0; i < listSongs.size(); i++) {
                String playerName = listSongs.get(i).get("songName").toString();// тут что укажу, по тому параметру и ищет
                if (textLength <= playerName.length()) {
                    //compare the String in EditText with Names in the ArrayList
                    if (searchString.equalsIgnoreCase(playerName.substring(0, textLength)))
                        listSongsForlistViewMainActivity.add(listSongs.get(i));
                }
            }

            adapterForListViewMainActivity.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну как то так:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < listSongs.size(); i++) {
            String songName = listSongs.get(i).get("songName").toString();
            String albumName = listSongs.get(i).get("albumName").toString();
            String artistName = listSongs.get(i).get("artistName").toString();

                if (searchString.equalsIgnoreCase(songName.substring(0, textLength)) || searchString.equalsIgnoreCase(albumName.substring(0, textLength)) || searchString.equalsIgnoreCase(artistName.substring(0, textLength)))
                    listSongsForlistViewMainActivity.add(listSongs.get(i));
            }
```

то есть, получаем все три строки для поиска и в условии сравниваем их по логическому OR - если одна из строк совпадает - условие истинно.

PS: условие можно сократить, если вынести обрезку из самого условия

А вообще это делается [по другому](http://blog.nkdroidsolutions.com/android-searchview-in-listview-example-tutorial/)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ и внимание но так почему-то не работает, хотя логика верна. Я уже такой ход проделывал...  хм....  т.е по имени находит, а вот по остальному нет

Comment: @ЛевашовВиталий Мне трудно сказать, почему неправильно, так как воспроизводимый пример создавать решительно лень. Посмотрите пример по ссылке внизу ответа (я ее обновил) - это должно вам помочь

Comment: !!!! Таки дошло :) простите ссылку пока не смотрел, но разобрался!!! Вы были правы по взаимоисключающему || работает но есть одно "но" !! код не найдет этот же трек по альбому или автору если в списке есть  другой трек который начинается на эту же буквы, во, родил :) т.е в первую очередь он ищет по имени...  И что же теперь делать......(мысли в слух произнес)

Comment: Дружище!!, это как раз то, что мне очень нужно!! Спасибо тебе большущее!!